# What is an upper bound for number of prime powers and semi primes in the interval $[n^2+1,n^2+n]?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

What is an upper bound for number of prime powers in the interval

$[n^2+1,n^2+n]?$

What is an upper bound for number of square free semi primes in this

interval$?$

Comment: Is this the continuation of the "upper bound" questions like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621089/what-is-an-upper-bound-for-number-of-semiprimes-in-the-interval-n2-n22n?noredirect=1#comment3304836_1621089 ?

Comment: there is a slight change, before it was in the interval $[n^2,(n+1)^2[$, today it is in $]n^2,(n+1)^2-n[$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say **an** upper bound, $n^2+ n$ is.

Comment: thanks...................How deeply you think!

Comment: I'm proud of making fun of some bodies in this website!

Comment: $n$ is a better bound, for that matter.